# Accessing Mojolicious helpers from a module using Mojo::Base?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have an existing application (my website) that I'm doing some code tidying in, and the tidy up is following the same sort of idea as the [`Mojo::Pg`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::Pg) example [here](https://github.com/kraih/mojo-pg/blob/master/examples/blog/lib/Blog/Model/Posts.pm), with separate model and controller files to keep things defined. My site accesses both Flickr and Last.fm's APIs, and I have a helper defined in `Site::Helpers`:

```
$app->helper(
    get_base_rest_url => sub {
        my ( $self, $config ) =  @_;

        sswitch ( $config ) {
            case 'photos': {
                my $base_url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/';
                my $user_id  = '7281432@N05';
                my $api_key  = $self->app->config->{ 'api_token' }{ 'flickr' };

                my $url =
                    "$base_url"
                    . "?user_id=$user_id"
                    . "&api_key=$api_key"
                    . "&per_page=" . $self->session->{ per_page }
                    . '&format=json'
                    . '&nojsoncallback=1';

                return $url;
            }

            case 'music': {
                my $base_url = 'https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/';
                my $username = 'virtualwolf';
                my $api_key  = $self->app->config->{ 'api_token' }{ 'last_fm' };
                my $per_page = $self->session->{ 'per_page' };

                my $url = "$base_url?user=$username&limit=$per_page&api_key=$api_key&format=json";

                return $url;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The problem I'm running into is that I don't know how to access that helper from the `Site::Model::Photos` module. The error is

```
Can't locate object method "get_base_rest_url" via package "Site::Model::Photos"
```

which is fair enough, but I can't work out how to actually get at that `get_base_rest_url` helper (or alternatively, how to access the `api_token` config).

Comment: Use the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) module (and possibly [`URI::QueryParam`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI::QueryParam)) for building elaborate URLs. Also, you shouldn't put simple scalar variables inside quotes, as in `"$base_url"`, Just `$base_url` is correct. I'm sorry that this has nothing to do with your stated problem, but I hoped you would appreciate the advice

Comment: I'd use [`Mojo::URL`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/URL) to construct the URL and [`->query`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/URL#query) to build it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your module have not got app attribute/method which get access to your app.

So, when you create instance of `Site::Model::Photos` you need to pass `app` to it in param and make it weaken something like that:

```
package Site::Model::Photos
use Scalar::Util 'weaken';
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $app = shift;
  my $hash = {app => $app, ...};
  weaken $hash->{app};
  return bless $hash, $class;
}

sub your_method {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->{app}->get_base_rest_url(...);
}

1;
```

Or you may to use this module https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious-Plugin-Model which do it for you:

```
package Site::Model::Photos
use Mojo::Base 'MojoX::Model';

... code of your module ...

sub your_method {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->app->get_base_rest_url(...);
}

1;
```

And in your App.pm  need to add this:

```
$app->plugin('Model', {namespaces => ['Site::Model']});
```

And use it that in controller:

```
$c->model('photos');
$c->app->model('photos');
```

Comment: The first suggestion just gave me a "Can't weaken a nonreference" error, but the second worked. Thanks!

Comment: First example should work. I have a proof of that:
https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/ce2b53c9647cf0204e81

To run: perl 1.pl get /

The result must be "zxc"

Comment: I also use the second variant with Mojolicious-Plugin-Model! Because very frequently need to pass $app to modules.